# Как передать много параметров в функцию, если они элементы массива?

Tags: php

Например, функция `array_diff()` принимает сколько угодно аргументов.

Как мне быть, если каждый аргумент-массив - это элемент массива? `$myArray = ...;`

Т.е.

```
array_diff($myArray[0], $myArray[1], $myArray[2], ... $myArray[N - 1]);
```

Каким образом мне передать все элементы массива в эту функцию?

Comment: Не это, случайно? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php)

```
function foo() {
    return func_get_args();
}

var_dump( foo([1], [2], [3]) );
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии PHP 5.6 вы можете делать [так](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list):

```
<?php
$myArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4],
    [5],
    [6],
    [7],
];
var_dump(array_diff(...$myArray));
```

[Тест](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68254d042a07582c219494f3a32e70ff70357f5b) вернет

```
array(1) {
  [7]=>
  int(8)
}
```